# Simplifying Boolean functions

Tags: boolean-algebra

How do I simplify the Boolean function: ABC + B
I've tried doing De Morgan's, but that doesn't do anything to simplify this. Can somebody show the steps on how to simplify this please?

Comment: Can you simplify to $A'+ABC=A'+BC$? And then one step further.

Comment: @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг How did you get that? I have no idea how

Comment: Is ABC mean A and B and C?.  Does B' mean not B?  Does + mean and?  Of or?

Comment: @fleablood Yes.  That is standard convention for Boolean-algebra.  $+$ is disjunction ("or"), and $\cdot$ is conjunction ("and"), while $x'$ is the negation of $x$.  Also, $1$ is true, and $0$ is false.

Comment: Usually, the previous notation means $(A \land B \land C)\lor \lnot A \lor \lnot C $

Comment: @joe , астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг used distribution and complementation: $A' + AX = (A'+A)(A'+X) = 1(A'+X)$

Comment: @GrahamKemp thank you for the clarification. Unfortunately the question changed after my comment, but now  the best way to do it is in fact, to go for karnaugh mapping.

Comment: @GrahamKemp How do you go from A′+AX to (A′+A)(A′+X) exactly?

Comment: @joe It is Distribution  $\rm X+YZ = (X+Y)(X+Z)$

Comment: @GrahamKemp thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DeMorgan's is the right way to go.

To get you started, it gives you: $$\begin{align}&\rm ABC+A'+C' \\[1ex]=~&\rm B(AC)+(AC)'\\[1ex] \ddots\end{align}$$

Now try distribution and simplify.  (Alt: you could distribute and simplify twice.)

Comment: distribute how exactly? I dont know any way to distribute that.

Comment: @joe In Boolean-algebra disjunction($+$) distributes over conjunction($\cdot$). $$\rm X+Y\cdot Z = (X+Y)\cdot (X+Z)$$

Answer (score 1):

$ABC+\bar{A} +\bar{C} = ABC+ \bar{A}BC+ \bar{A} +\bar{C} =BC + \bar{A} +\bar{C}$.

$BC + \bar{A} +\bar{C}= BC + \bar{A} +\bar{C} + B\bar{C}= B + \bar{A} +\bar{C}$.

Comment: how do you get from ABC + A' + C' to ABC + A'BC + A' + C'? what theorem do you use?

Comment: It is easy to verify using a truth table that $X = X + XY$ for any $Y$. Hence $\bar{A} = \bar{A}+ \bar{A}BC$.